# Battery is getting drained very fast

Tags: ubuntu, battery, sony-vaio, battery-life

My laptop is approx. 18 month old.  I have changed the internal hard drive recently and I have Ubuntu installed on the system.

The problem is my laptop's battery is draining very fast.  When it charges up to 100%, it shows 1:15 minutes remaining. Can any one tell me the possible reasons for the short battery life?

Comment: There are many possible reasons.  you need to start troubleshooting to determine where the problem lays.  To start, try a replacement battery.

Comment: `Even i charged it 100 % then also it show 1:15 min remaining.` Are you saying that it *only* shows 1:15 remaining with a full charge or that it says that but only lasts a few minutes? If it actually lasts that long, then it is not really unusual. Even with a full charge, a battery may not last too long, depending on how you are using the laptop. If it says 1:15, but only lasts a few minutes, then something *might* be wrong, though again, that may have merely been an estimate, and your usage could affect how fast it drains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Batteries have a limited life and they usually begin to degrade [after a couple of years](http://www.ebay.com/gds/What-is-the-Average-Life-Expectancy-of-Standard-Laptop-Batteries-/10000000177629697/g.html). It could be time for a replacement.

Answer (score 0):

Install and run Powertop  (`apt-get install powertop`).  This should help identify some of the issues.